# Transform JSON to a predefined array of objects

Tags: javascript

Given the JSON response below:

```js
const result = {
  'potential': {
    A: 514,
    B: 3127,
    C: 2970,
    D: 282,
    E: 41,
    F: 1,
    undefined: 48,
  },
  'current': {
    A: 2,
    B: 961,
    C: 2897,
    D: 2568,
    E: 455,
    F: 47,
    G: 5,
    undefined: 48,
  },
};
```

I need to transform it to:

```js
const temp = [
  { rating: 'A', potential: 514, current: 2 },
  { rating: 'B', potential: 3127, current: 961 },
  { rating: 'C', potential: 2970, current: 2897 },
  { rating: 'D', potential: 282, current: 2568 },
  { rating: 'E', potential: 41, current: 455 },
  { rating: 'F', potential: 1, current: 47 },
  { rating: 'G', potential: 0, current: 5 },
];
```

I manage by doing:

```js
// Get unique list of keys
const allKeysSet = new Set(Object.keys(result).map(keys => Object.keys(result[keys])).flat().sort());

// Get feature names
const features = Object.keys(result);
const temp = [];

allKeysSet.forEach(s => {
  // Get features object with corresponding values, if undefined return 0
  const r = features.reduce((a, b) =>  ({ [a]: result[a][s] || 0, [b]: result[b][s] || 0 }));

  temp.push( { reference: s, ...r} );
});

console.log(temp);
```

If there is a simpler/efficient way of doing this, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Review, I have two questions: I executed your code and `undefined` key is included in the output, it is correct ?  From the example you posted it seems me the keys are always equal in `potential` and `current`, it is always the expected scenario ?

Comment: the undefined values, could be different, but I'm removing them from temp at the moment, I keep them just in case we need to classified them in the future.

Comment: Just a quick note: I don't see what juggling with `Object.keys` and `Set`s nets you, as you could use `Object.entries` to cut out most of the code for `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that can be useful to simplify your code is about the structure of the input data that contains almost the same keyset both in the `potential` and `current` properties, while the output contains the union of the two keysets. This suggests that [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=it) can help you to simplify your code, so you can unpack the `potential` and `current` properties of your initial `data` object into two different variables called `potential`and `current` and obtain the union of the two keysets:

```
const {potential, current} = data; //<-- input data 
const allKeysSet = new Set(Object.keys(potential));
Object.keys(current).forEach(key => allKeysSet.add(key));
```

Your idea of using `reduce` and iterate over the keys of your `data` object is correct: you can transform your union keyset into an array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?retiredLocale=it) and can use the logical Nullish_coalescing_operator [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to insert a default value (in your case 0):

```js
const data = {
    'potential': {
      A: 514,
      B: 3127,
      C: 2970,
      D: 282,
      E: 41,
      F: 1,
    },
    'current': {
      A: 2,
      B: 961,
      C: 2897,
      D: 2568,
      E: 455,
      F: 47,
      G: 5,
    },
};
const {potential, current} = data;
const allKeysSet = new Set(Object.keys(potential));
Object.keys(current).forEach(key => allKeysSet.add(key));

const result = Array.from(allKeysSet).sort().reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc.push({'rating': key, 'potential': potential[key] ?? 0, 'current': current[key] ?? 0});
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the `G` in `current` is lost, it needs to be set to 0 if it does  not exist in one or the other

Comment: @RicardoSanchez I made an error, I'm modifying my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Combine two keys from `potential` & `current` store result in `keys` variable array using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), Excluding `undefined` value by [`filter`](https://%5B%60Array.map()%60%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) and with help of [`map`](https://%5B%60Array.map()%60%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) create `temp` array:

```js
const result = { 'potential': { A: 514, B: 3127, C: 2970, D: 282, E: 41, F: 1, undefined: 48, }, 'current': { A: 2, B: 961, C: 2897, D: 2568, E: 455, F: 47, G: 5, undefined: 48, }, };
const {potential:potentials, current:currents} = result;
const keys = [...new Set(Object.keys(potentials).concat(Object.keys(currents)))].filter(key=>key!='undefined'); // [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" ]
const temp = keys.map(key=>({rating:key,potential:potentials[key]??0,current:currents[key]??0}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp, null, 4))
```

Comment: While this might be a good answer on stackoverflow, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).